# Populating Matrix array with integers read in from file in ADA programming language

Tags: arrays, matrix, ada

I need a little help attempting to populate a matrix of size 3 by 5 with numbers read in from an external file in Ada programming. 
The external file contains two rows of 15 digits:

```
1  3 8 4 10 2  4  38 43 4 8 12 32 16 6
23 8 9 9 18 41 11 21 12 2 1 6  33 11 22
```

Here's the code I have so far. I know that I can populate the array when reading from the file but I'm having trouble getting the syntax correctly. To be clear there are two matrices which need to be populated each 3x5 from the external file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure lab06 is   
   package Flt_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO(FLOAT);
   use Flt_IO;

   MAX_ROW1 : constant := 3;
   MAX_COL1 : constant := 5;
   MAX_ROW2 : constant := 3;
   MAX_COL2 : constant := 5;
   n: NATURAL := 0;
   I: INTEGER := 0;
   type MATRIX_1 is array(INTEGER range 1..MAX_ROW1, INTEGER range 1..MAX_COL1) of INTEGER;
   type MATRIX_2 is array(INTEGER range 1..MAX_ROW2, INTEGER range 1..MAX_COL2) of INTEGER;  
   First : MATRIX_1;
   inf : FILE_TYPE;
begin 
   Open(inf, In_File, "lab06.in");
   loop 
      exit when End_Of_File(inf);
      Get(inf,n);
      First(I) := n;
      I := I + 1;
   end loop;
   Put(n);
   Close(inf);
end Lab06;
```

Comment: So both `MATRIX_1` and `MATRIX_2` need to have the same contents in the end?

Comment: @morido no MATRIX_1 should have the first 15 integers and MATRIX_2 should have the remaining 15 in it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any idea about how the numbers are organised?

Comment: Have you considered putting your focus on the matrices instead of on the file?  It might help.  Also: You can iterate over the elements of a matrix with `for Element of Some_Matrix loop ... end loop;`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really pretty, but here is a possible solution:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure lab06 is   
   MAX_ROW : constant := 3;
   MAX_COL : constant := 5;
   type MATRIX is array(NATURAL range 1..MAX_ROW, NATURAL range 1..MAX_COL) of NATURAL;
   Inf : FILE_TYPE;
   Matrix_1 : MATRIX;
   Matrix_2 : MATRIX;

   procedure PopulateMatrix(Inf : in FILE_TYPE; Result : out MATRIX) is 
      I: INTEGER := 0;
   begin
      loop
        declare
         N : NATURAL;
         Row : Natural;
         Column : Natural;
        begin       
         Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(inf,N);
         Column := (I rem MAX_COL) +1;
         Row := (I - Column-1) / MAX_ROW +1;

         Result(Row, Column) := N;
         I := I + 1;
         exit when I = MAX_ROW * MAX_COL;
       end;
      end loop;
   end PopulateMatrix;

   procedure PrintMatrix(Input : in MATRIX) is 
   begin
      for Row in MATRIX'Range(1) loop
       for Column in MATRIX'Range(2) loop
        Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Input(Row, Column));
       end loop;
       Put_Line("");
      end loop;     
   end PrintMatrix;

begin 
   Open(Inf, In_File, "lab06.in");
   PopulateMatrix(Inf, Matrix_1);
   PopulateMatrix(Inf, Matrix_2);
   Close(Inf);

   PrintMatrix(Matrix_1);
   Put_Line("");
   PrintMatrix(Matrix_2);   
end Lab06;
```

This gives you:

```
1          3          8          4         10
2          4         38         43          4
8         12         32         16          6

23          8          9          9         18
41         11         21         12          2
1          6         33         11         22
```

I hope this gets at least close to your expected output (which you have not really defined anywhere...).

Comment: In `PopulateMatrix`, why not use the same iteration scheme used in `PrintMatrix`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289035/populating-matrix-array-with-integers-read-in-from-file-in-ada-programming-langu#comment58289763_35289035)?

Comment: @trashgod I tried to stay as close as possible to the OP's code (which uses an unconditional loop). But for loops would probably make it more readable, I agree. - Anyhow, I will leave it for now and wait for the OP's opinion. Feel free to post your own answer based on mine, though.

Comment: @trashgod thanks alot is there any possible way i can make another procedure and multiply these two matrices from index (1,1) -(3-5) and store them in another array?

Comment: @chriskelly Certainly. You could simply amend the logic inside the ˋPrintMatrixˋ procedure to multiply the matrices instead of dumping them to the console.

Comment: @morido im still a little lost on how to implement the multiplication i think it would go something like this but this wont run thanks.            Matrix_1(1,1)*Matrix_2(1,1)=c(1,1) 
Matrix_1(1,2)*Matrix_2(1,2)=c(1,2) 
 Matrix_1(1,3)*Matrix_3(1,3)=c(1,3)
      ...
 Matrix_1(3,5)*Matrix_2(3,5)=c(3,5)

Comment: @trashgod would it be easier to make a new procedure passing in both matrices and multiplying each index

Comment: @chriskelly How about asking a new question regarding this multiplication issue? It's completely unrelated to what we have so far...